# Launch an Activity from a custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I'm trying to launch an activity from a custom lisview. I have hoded the onItemclick method nd called the class by creating a new intent!

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    if (position == 0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InstalledApps.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

but when I try to launch it, it gives me a nullpointer exception. what I'm trying to do is, get the position of the clicked item and direct it to the correct activity by an if clause. the following is the log cat output.

```
07-05 04:39:52.718: W/dalvikvm(3189): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at com.sliit.droidman.thirdpartyapplist.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:69)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at     android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please let me know what I'm doing wrong here!

the adapter class.

```
 package com.sliit.droidman.thirdpartyapplist;
 import com.sliit.droidman.R;

 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.ViewGroup;  
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;  
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;  

 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  
 {  
Activity context;  
String title[];  
String description[];
Drawable icon[];

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description , Drawable[] ico) {  
    super();  
    this.context = context;  
    this.title = title;  
    this.description = description;
    this.icon = ico;
}  

public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return title.length;  
}  

public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

private class ViewHolder {  
    TextView txtViewTitle;  
    TextView txtViewDescription;
    ImageView image;
}  

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    ViewHolder holder;  
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();  

    if (convertView == null)  
    {  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);  
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);  
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packagename);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        convertView.setTag(holder);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }  

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);  
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    holder.image.setImageDrawable(icon[position]);

return convertView;  
}  

 }
```

Comment: post your getView(ListViewAdapter.java:69) method and class..

Comment: I added it! nd I cant see there is an error in the adapter class! :(

Comment: Specify please the exact line of code that gives the exception, this will make the issue a lot more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`07-05 04:39:52.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3189):     at com.sliit.droidman.thirdpartyapplist.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:69)`

You have a null pointer at line 69 of `com.sliit.droidman.thirdpartyapplist.ListViewAdapter`'s `getView` method. Figure out what's causing that null pointer and make sure it doesn't happen.

It appears that line 69 is the following

```
    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
```

Some things that might cause this:

- Perhaps the title array is null. I think if it were just that the `position` argument were too large, you'd get an  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException instead.
- The `txtViewTitle` member of the `holder` instance is `null`, possibly because the id `R.id.appname` is incorrect in line 59.

You can figure this out by putting a breakpoint on line 69 in the debugger and inspecting the values of `holder.txtViewTitle` and `title`.

Comment: As well as the answer above, this actually doesn't answer the user's question. You should post a comment trying to figure out what exactly is on that line of code and then try to help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.sliit.droidman.thirdpartyapplist;
 import com.sliit.droidman.R;

 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.ViewGroup;  
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;  
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;  

 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  
 {  
Activity context;  
String title[];  
String description[];
Drawable icon[];

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description , Drawable[] ico) {  
    super();  
    this.context = context;  
    this.title = title;  
    this.description = description;
    this.icon = ico;
}  

public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return title.length;  
}  

public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

 //You have to overide the getView method
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{  
    //added row, to convert view
    View row = convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder;  


    if (convertView == null)  
    {  
        //added casting to the context 
         LayoutInflater inflater =  ((Activity)this.context).getLayoutInflater();    
        //made changes here
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, parent, false);  
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);  
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packagename);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        row.setTag(holder);  
    }  
    else  
    {   //added row
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();  
    }  

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);  
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    holder.image.setImageDrawable(icon[position]);
//changed to row
return row;  
}  

 }  
static  class ViewHolder {  
    TextView txtViewTitle;  
    TextView txtViewDescription;
    ImageView image;
}
```

Basically, I created a static ViewHolder class outside the class of your listadapter, and made couple other minor changes, including overriding your getView method. I left comments where I made changes. Let me know if this works!  Hope this helps!